# Is there anyway to derive the number of water molecules in a hydrated salt, given just the formula for the anhydrous salt?

Tags: water, coordination-compounds

Is there anyway to derive the number of water molecules in a hydrated salt, given just the formula for the anhydrous salt?

That's pretty much it. If not, why?

For coordinated water, my guess is counting the number of unfilled pairs in the metal ion or something like that would give us an indication of the number of water molecules.

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Comment: For a given salt there may be lots of hydrates.

Comment: @Mithoron Come on! Science can't be that arbitrary. There must be something

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_chloride#Structure,_preparation,_and_general_properties

Comment: I disagree that this question is too broad, other than the fact that it is of general interest, even if the answer is not much more complicated than "no".

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon This matter is much more complicated. One can't just derive it with simple equation, but there can be guesses similar to what OP proposes, sometimes it would work other times not. One could use various computational methods to estimate enthalpies of hydrates one by one to find which probably exist. No doubt there's middle ground between these approaches, but it seems like putting whole book summary into few posts.

Comment: @Mithoron "No doubt there's middle ground between these approaches" If such an approach exists, I have never heard of it, and it would make a great answer.